# Update user fields with rails on devise custom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise and i am trying to update extra fields has user log in. So in order for me to be able to update my user.longitude i had to create in new controller who is acting has the rails controller sessions. Here the code I have

```
class MysessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    self.resource.longitude = params[:longitude]
    self.resource.update_attributes(params[:longitude])
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

  end
end
```

I know it doesn't follow restfull and it doesnt work but i need to be able to update my user field and i am not sure how to do, this doesn't give me anything wrong, but it doesn't also modify it properly. Thank for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
self.resource.update_attributes(params[:longitude])
```

Might return false if the record is invalid and silently fail. Check that out first.

Second, you might want to take a look into alias_method_chain instead of copying the content of the create action of your inherited controller.

Otherwise, this is to update a record after a user logged in. You should save the longitude AFTER he signs in. Wherever you redirect the user after he signs in, let the following call handle the longitude update. Easy way could be to store the longitude in session if it needs to survive.

Comment: What do u mean if it is invalid? or silently fail

Comment: The return value of update_attributes is true or false. If it would fail, it'd be false. Your record would not be updated but it would still carry on. Take a look here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes

Comment: Thanks, i think i found my error, and this was helpfull thanks